# Python Selenium find url and switch to next page

Tags: python, selenium

This sript is working, but as I know that there are more urls available, what do I need to add in order to switch to the next page.
for example, I like to get all urls on the first, second and third google page?
Thanks for your help!

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path = "c:\\...\\geckodriver.exe")
url = "https://www.google.de"
driver.get(url)

actions = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)

time.sleep(4)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='tsf']/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/input")
element.send_keys('restaurant in hamburg');
element.submit()
time.sleep(2)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(browser_profile=fp)

htmltext = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext, "lxml")
ergebnisse = soup.find_all ("div", class_="rc")

for result in results:
    link = result.find ("a",href=True)
    print (link.get('href'))

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi AMC, yes I've tried some answers from other posts but did not succeed and could not find anything within the docu https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html

Comment: Just to be clear, you’re asking how to go to the next page of results on google or whatever, not how to follow the links your parsed, right?

Comment: yes, right, I like to include into the script to go to the next page in order to append the 'href' to the list of url's. I have found out, that the tag is called:     <a aria-label="Page 2" class="fl" href="/search... e.g. for the second page but could not find out, how to include it.

Comment: Are you sure there was nothing in the docs? All you need to do is click the button, like you normally would.

Comment: Everything I have included in my script was not running ... e.g. dropdown_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-toggle='dropdown']")))
    #dropdown_button.click()

Answer (score 0):

Navigating different pages through selenium isn't any different than normal browsing. Create a variable and set it to an element that will bring you to the next page(the next button or the '2'nd page option). You can then use  `.click()` to click the element. Then loop through the part that gets your urls and repeat for each consecutive page.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have an idea, how to find the id from the different pages as they vary and how to define it? I have tried it that way: page_button = driver.find_element_by_id('a aria-label="Page 2"')  in order to reach the second page but did not succeed.

Comment: @Move_on It should be easier to locate the next page button, as it should be the same(the next page button  id='pnnext') regardless of which page of google you are on. It looks like you can locate by id using ` next_page_variable_here = driver.find_element_by_id("pnnext")`